# ROS2 how can I call a service and wait for the response from within a subscriber callback?

Tags: ros, c++, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to continue to spin but know when the request is available, using C++

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294881/ros2-how-can-i-call-a-service-and-wait-for-the-response-from-within-a-subscriber-callback?/) by [vandy2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/36002/vandy2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not currently possible, so you'll have to do an asynchronous service call, starting it in the subscription callback and finishing it in a callback when the response is received. Here's an example:

https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/06f25e9c8801ea95a0c25260cb38f2f0c6af3ea0/demo_nodes_cpp/src/services/add_two_ints_client_async.cpp#L62-L73

In general, it's a bad idea to block in a subscription (or service, or timer) callback since that prevents other callbacks from being handled.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2